# SAPUI5 Create Controller Without View

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, sapui5

I am developing an application by using SAPUI5, Web IDE. Is it possible to create a controller without a view? Because I need a custom controller to process the logic of application before submit it to the server.

I try to create a controller without with view. But it return me with error.

The following is my sample code.

```
/*global location*/
sap.ui.define([
    "product/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
    "product/model/formatter"
], function(BaseController, JSONModel, History, formatter) {

        onInit: function() {
            sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().subscribe(
                "SomeChannel",
                "SomeEvent",
                this.someFunctionOfTheFirstController,
                this
            );
        }

    processLogic: function (sChannelId, sEventId, sData) {
        console.log(
            "Function of the first controller " + sData
        );
    }
});
```

Any solution how can I fix it and to create a controller and method without a view.

Comment: Why does that need to be a controller though. Your `define` can return a function or an object, it doesn't need to extend the controller. Return a function you can use to subscribe to the event bus and use it in the other controller?

Comment: After my I include my new controller in "define", It return error and I can't navigate to the page which include new controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to return the controller object itself. You are importing the BaseController, so your controller could look like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "product/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
    "product/model/formatter"
], function(BaseController, JSONModel, History, formatter) {

    return BaseController.extend("product.controller.MyController", {
        onInit: function() {
            sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().subscribe(
                "SomeChannel",
                "SomeEvent",
                this.someFunctionOfTheFirstController,
                this
            );
        },

        processLogic: function (sChannelId, sEventId, sData) {
            console.log("Function of the first controller " + sData);
        }
   });
});
```

Afterwards you can load your controller by calling:

```
const myController = sap.ui.controller("product.controller.MyController");
```